# setting functions for dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript

I have a table with dynamically generated content. Each row comes with a button that is meant to serve that row. In my case I want my button's outerHTML to adopt the name of the name on its row.

I am having trouble assigning `this` to my onclick event. As is, clicking either button will only repeat the name on the first row. I am unsure of the exact proper syntax for getting the button to change to its appropriate row name.

```js
var erray = ["Todd", "Bill", "Sam"];
var pname = document.querySelectorAll('.pname');
var adoptname = document.querySelectorAll('.adoptname');

for (var i = 0; i < erray.length; i++){
    var adoptname = document.querySelectorAll('.adoptname');
    pname[i].innerText = erray[i];

    adoptname[i].onclick = adoption;

    function adoption(){
        for (var i = 0; i < pname.length; i++)
            this.outerHTML = pname[i].innerHTML;
    }
}
```

```css
table { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table>
<thead><tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Adopt</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td class="pname"></td><td><button class="adoptname">Adopt</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="pname"></td><td><button class="adoptname">Adopt</button></td></tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
<thead><tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Adopt</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody id="table_body">
<tr><td class="pname"></td><td><button class="adoptname">Adopt</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="pname"></td><td><button class="adoptname">Adopt</button></td></tr>    
</tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload=function()
{
  var array=["Todd","Bill","Sam"];

  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
  {
     $("#table_body tr:nth-child("+(i+1)+") .pname").html(array[i]);
     $("#table_body tr:nth-child("+(i+1)+") .adoptname").attr("id","adopt-"+array[i]);
  }


  $("#table_body").on("click","[id^=adopt]",function(){
         var id=$(this).attr("id");
         var name=id.split("-")[1];
         alert(name);
  });
  }

 </script>
```

Comment: Copying your code appears to lead to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/86zp2721/), which still does not function.

Comment: Now I have checked and added the full working code. Check it now.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your html is like this;

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Adopt</th>
   </thead>

   <tbody id="table_body">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Now look at the js

```
var array=["Todd","Bill","Sam"];
var html="";

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
   html=html+"<tr><td>"+array[i]+"</td><td><button id=\"adopt-"+array[i]+"\">Adopt</button>";
}

$("#table_body").html(html);
```

Now look at the click event;

```
$("#table_body").on("click","[id^=adopt]",function(){
             var id=$(this).attr("id");
             var name=id.split("-")[1];
             alert(name);
 })
```

Comment: You have a typo on `table-body`. I believe it should be `table_body`. In addition, I am also unsure what `table-event` id refers to. Regarding my question, I don't actually need to generate the entire table row. I have a view engine do that for me. All I need is to make the function trigger to its designated row.

Comment: If you don't want to generate a full row then you can follow my 2nd answer.

Comment: Can you clarify where `#table_event` is assigned? I tried modifying the button to `<button class=\"table-event\" id=\"adopt-"+array[i]+"\">Adopt</button>"` and then switched the click call from an id to the class `$(".table-event")`. However, it did not do anything.

Comment: Sorry I did mistake again after edit. Now made the change; it should work. table_event 'll be table_body. Change it else every think keep same as my code.